# Calculation of $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin (\pi\cos^2 x)}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus

Calculation of $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin (\pi\cos^2 x)}{x^2}$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Given $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin (\pi\cos^2 x)}{x^2} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin (\pi (1-\sin^2 x))}{x^2}$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin (\pi \sin^2 x)}{\pi\sin^2 x} \times \pi \times \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2} = \pi$

Is there is any other method by which we can solve the above question.

If yes, The please help me .

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with L'Hospital's Rule?  But your method is nicer.

Comment: I don't sse what the second line has to do with the first line in your "My Try" section. Where did the $1-$ go?

Comment: $\sin(\pi -t)=\sin t$.

Comment: if we do L'Hospital rule we may get answer as zero..am i right?

Comment: If we use L'Hospital's Rule, we get $\pi$.

Comment: hm yaa u r right i tried it again thank u :)

Comment: L'Hopital is very messy after the first round of derivative. Is there any other method?