# What is $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(\pi \cos^2x)}{x^2}= \ ?$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need help with this problem

> $\large \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(\pi 
> \cos^2x)}{x^2}= \ ?$
>
> A. $1$
>
> B. $\pi$
>
> C. $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$
>
> D. $-\pi$

EDIT ::: In the light  of hint by Mr @G. Sassatelli , here is my try

[image]

Comment: @StackTD L.R  and i get $pi$

Comment: What do you mean "L.R"? The answer is indeed $\pi$.

Comment: Please avoid display-style in the title.

Comment: @StackTD  L'Hôpital's rule

Comment: I suggest the identity $\sin t=\sin(\pi-t)$.

Comment: See this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744713/calculation-of-lim-x-rightarrow-0-frac-sin-pi-cos2-xx2?rq=1

Comment: You can check out https://tex.stackexchange.com/ if you are having trouble  typing mathematical symbols. It makes the question look better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to thank   @G. Sassatelli  for the hint

Here is my try

[image]